# Choose an option of a JSF SelectOneMenu with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jsf, selectonemenu

I have a JSF `selectOneMenu` and need to select option 2 (out of 3) dynamically with jQuery. I use the `$('[id$=tripple_choice]').show();` `$('[id$=tripple_choice]').hide();` to show/hide the whole menu.

UPDATE:

The generated HTML is:

```
<select name="view:custform:tripple_choice" size="1" class="" id="view:custform:tripple_choice">
  <option value="" selected="true">-- Select --</option>
  <option value="opt1">opt1</option>
  <option value="opt2">opt2</option>
</select>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
$('[id$=tripple_choice]').eq(1).show();
```

You can use `:eq` expression in your selector as well...

```
$('[id$=tripple_choice]:eq(1)').show();
```

... but this is actually discouraged by jQuery:

> Because :eq() is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :eq() cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. For better performance in modern browsers, use
>   $("your-pure-css-selector").eq(index) instead.

UPDATE: in your case you need to update the `selectedIndex` property of HTMLSelectObject. It's done with this line...

```
$('[id$=tripple_choice]')[0].selectedIndex = 1;
```

Comment: thanks, bit it's not working at all :( Maybe because of our modified JSF framework. What would be the equivalent in plain javascript?

Comment: Can you show the HTML structure created? I wonder why did you use `id$=` selector in the first place...

Comment: @user1414745 Thank you; updated my answer. Should work now. )